# Finding the value of a class within a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<ul id="list">
<li data-markerid="0" class="">
<div class="list-label">A</div>
<div class="list-details">
    <div class="list-content">
        <div class="loc-id">2</div>
        <div class="loc-addr">England</div>
        <div class="loc-dist">2 miles</div>
        <div class="loc-addr2">Test</div> 
        <div class="loc-addr2">Bristol</div> 
    </div>
</div>
</li>

<li data-markerid="1" class="">
<div class="list-label">A</div>
<div class="list-details">
    <div class="list-content">
        <div class="loc-id">3</div>
        <div class="loc-addr">England</div>
        <div class="loc-dist">60 miles</div>
        <div class="loc-addr2">Test</div> 
        <div class="loc-addr2">London</div> 
    </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'm wanting to extract the value of this using JQuery.

I tried:

```
var targetID = $(this).find('.loc-id').text();
```

But this gets me values of both loc-id's. I want just the one that I'm selecting (clicking).

For full context, please look here: [Parsing data using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384392/parsing-data-using-jquery/24384636#24384636)

```
 $('#list').click(function () {
    //Change the src of img
    var targetID = $(this).find('.loc-id').text();  // Get the ID

    // Since array of objects isn't indexed, need to loop to find the correct one
    var foundObject = null;
    for (var key in parsedArray) {
        if (parsedArray.hasOwnProperty(key) && parsedArray[key].id == targetID) {
            foundObject = parsedArray[key];
            break;
        }
    }

    // If the object is found, extract the image and set!
    if (!foundObject)
        return;

    var imageSrc = foundObject.LocationPhoto; // From the object
    $('#location-image').attr('src', imageSrc); // Set the new source
});
```

Thanks

Comment: How & where are you using `var targetID = $(this).find('.loc-id').text();`? Show complete code.

Comment: where are you clicking..?

Comment: @Satpal Look at original question for full context.

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the `ul` and has more than 1 `.loc-id`.

Comment: You say : "this gets me values of both loc-id's". But your selector uses a class an not an ID, so it's normal to get 2 results if ($this) represents your list `<ul>`

Comment: So, considering the original question, your will always get 2 values, if your click on `#list`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e9gz9/

Comment: Is there any reason I've been downvoted to oblivion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler, `this` references the `<ul>` element which has multiple `<li>` children.

Change the click handler to act as a delegate instead:

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li', function () {
```

Now, inside the click handler, `this` references an `<li>` element so the search should only yield a single value.

Answer (score 1):

For `var targetID = $(this).find('.loc-id').text();` to work, you must be clicking an element that is an ascendant of only one `.loc-id`. For example:

```
$('.list-details').on('click',function(){
    var targetID = $(this).find('.loc-id').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change selector. In your event handler. `$(this)` referes to `ul` which has multiple `loc-id` thus when you are using `text()` its concatenating text.

Use

```
$('#list li').click(function () {
    //Change the src of img
    var targetID = $(this).find('.loc-id').text(); // Get the ID
    alert('targetID: ' + targetID)
});
```

instead of

```
// When we select the item
$('#list').click(function () {
    //Change the src of img
    var targetID = $(this).find('.loc-id').text();  // Get the ID
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9gz9/)

Comment: This is really good, thanks but I had an issue with #list li firing an event but logically it's on the ball.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `event.target` in case you are delegating on `#list`:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/CxcU8/***

```
$("#list").on("click", function(e) {
    var $t = $(e.target);
    if ($t.hasClass('loc-id')) {
        alert($t.text());
    }
});
```